# MySQL Query - Transpose

Tags: mysql

How if I have this 1 column and want to make it become 1 row. 
Please Help using MYSQL Query. Thank you.

```
Column
------
1
0
1
1
0
1
0 


  Col1       Col2       Col3     Col4      Col5      Col6       Col7
| 1        | 0        | 1      | 1       | 0       | 1        | 0      |
```

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table) is a good article, where you can find answer.