# Column names in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'd like to get column names from mysql table which does not have particular value

```
MyTable:
------------------------------------------
| col1  |  col2  |  col3 | col4  | col5  |
|       |        |       |       |       |
|  12   |   -    |   50  |   -   |  10   |
|       |        |       |       |       |
------------------------------------------
```

I want column names which is not having value '-'

```
Output :
-----------------
|  col1  |  12  |
|  col3  |  15  |
|  col5  |  10  |
-----------------
```

Is there a query for this?

want output like:

```
SELECT coloumn_names FROM table_name WHERE column_value != '-' AND other_col_value='some_value'
```

where some_col_value is unique field

Comment: Your table only has one row?

Comment: @Barmar no but there is another unique column say col6 and i will filter it with where clause like where col6=some_number

Comment: @Barmar A bad cut'n'paste... The link was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943388/mysql-query-transpose). Thank you for the reporting.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini That's still the opposite. Most pivot questions want to turn rows into columns. He wants to turn columns into rows.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix code with data.
the moment you want to select a column name (which is a part of the program) as a mere data - you know you're doing something wrong.

You need another table structure for this.
It have to be vertical, not horizontal.

Just make it

```
id | key  | value  | 
 1   col1    12
 1   col2     -
 1   col3    50
 1   col4     -
 1   col5    10
```

where `id` - identifier from your old table

```
select key from old join new on id where value='-' and col6='whatever'
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice but my table contains almost 20 columns having thousands of record and now if i try convert into table as u said it will not work

Comment: it will. More than that - it is the only way.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT "col1" colName, col1 colValue
FROM MyTable
WHERE col1 != "-" AND col6 = some_number
UNION
SELECT "col2", col2
FROM MyTable
WHERE col2 != "-" AND col6 = some_number
UNION
SELECT "col3", col3
FROM MyTable
WHERE col3 != "-" AND col6 = some_number
UNION
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 SHOW COLUMNS FROM `tablename` where 'condition'
```

and for further detail please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html
hope its help

Comment: Its just an idea.I had mentioned link for further detail.

Comment: It will more easier rather then making a seprate table and hashing column over there.and join to fetch name again.My idea is to get column names and then loop through if they are empty or not.